# How to use a real solver to solve a complex equation?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's assume I have a solver for finding x for a given linear equation $Ax =b$,  where $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and real, and   $b$ is a real   vector  which has a length $n$, $x$ is the solution for  the linear equation. So it is clear that the solver can solve any real  matrix equation.

What will happen if we  $C$ is $n \times n$  **complex** matrix and , and   $m$ is a complex   vector  which has a length $n$. Can I use the same solver for solving the q?

$$ Cq = m$$

The way I'm thinking about this problem, is

We can rewrite the equation,

$$ Cq = m$$
$$ (C_R + C_I)(q_R + q_I) = m_R + m_I$$

I = imaginary component 
R= Real Component

Using  the above strategy we  we separate the real part to use the solver I have mentioned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a *solver*?

Comment: Solver is like a program  you use to solve a linear equation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You have to remember that $C_Iq_I$ contributes to $m_R$.  You are essentially writing $C$ as a $2n \times 2n$ (real) matrix and $q,m$ as (real) vectors of length $2n$ and solving that.  It partitions as 
$$\begin {pmatrix} C_R&-C_I\\C_I&C_R \end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} q_R\\q_I \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} m_R\\m_I \end {pmatrix}$$ in analogy with representing complex $a+bi$ as $\begin {pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end {pmatrix}$

Comment: I understand  your formation of the matrix, could you please extend your answer a little bit explaining why the matrix equation you have written will be run by the real SOLVER i mentioned.

Comment: The solver doesn't know anything is complex.  All the entries are real.  The entries in $C_I$ are the imaginary parts of $C$, but remember that $Im(a+bi)=b$, which is real.  The solver is happy to go ahead and solve it.  You then reassemble the real and imaginary parts into complex numbers when the solution is done.

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Since the solver is  for real matrices, can't we seperate  the equation  in the form of solver (a=bx)? If I can do that I apply that solver to the real part only. AM I missing something ?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of the equation mix because multiplying two imaginaries gives a real.  It sounds like you are trying to solve $C_Rq_R=m_R$ and the corresponding imaginary equation separately, which cannot be done.  My version has $C_Rq_R-C_Iq_I=m_R$ and the corresponding imaginary equation.  Note the mixing, but in this format all the values in the matrices and vectors are real.

Comment: SO you are saying, although the elements in the C is in complex form but we can write in matrix with only with the real elements. Another thing is that, you didn't write  the imaginary q matrix like C.  IS it because it is length of n? I mean if the length of a  complex vector is n, we can write it  as a single column matrix .

Comment: $C_R$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with each entry being the real part of the corresponding entry of $C$.  $C_I$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix with each entry being the imaginary part of the corresponding entry of $C$.  The big matrix in my solution is $2n \times 2n$ shown as four $n \times n$ quadrants.  My vector that has $q_R$ and $q_I$ is of length $2n$ with the real parts of $q$ followed by the imaginary parts of $q$ (without the $i$s, so they are real numbers), similarly for the $m$.  This recasts the $n$ complex equations as $2n$ real equations, so your real solver can handle it fine.

Comment: Thanks for details  explanation. :)

Comment: It is like solving $z^2=1+i$.  One might say "I don't know how to take complex square roots".  Another approach is to write $z=a+bi$ and the equation becomes $a^2-b^2+2abi=1+i$.  You can now equate real and imaginary parts, getting $a^2-b^2=1, 2ab=1$ and now you have two real equations in two unknowns to solve.

Comment: Yeah this is the the strategy i was thinking  in the very beginning.